# Publish message to topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm trying to figure out how to publish the same message to a topic. Problem is that topic can consists of subscriptions from iOS and Android users, and there is different payload for iOS and Android.

If I have hashtags users are subscribed to. Do I have to create double topics (iOS+Android) for the same tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Publish` function of Amazon SNS permits different payloads to be delivered to subscribers of different messaging services.

From [Send Custom Platform-Specific Payloads in Messages to Mobile Devices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-custommessage.html):

> To send a message to an app installed on devices for multiple platforms, such as GCM and APNS, you must first subscribe the mobile endpoints to a topic in Amazon SNS and then publish the message to the topic. The following example shows a message to send to subscribed mobile endpoints on APNS, GCM, and ADM:

```
{ 
"default": "This is the default message which must be present when publishing a message to a topic. The default message will only be used if a message is not present for 
one of the notification platforms.",     
"APNS": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\": \"Check out these awesome deals!\",\"url\":\"www.amazon.com\"} }",
"GCM":"{\"data\":{\"message\":\"Check out these awesome deals!\",\"url\":\"www.amazon.com\"}}",
"ADM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"Check out these awesome deals!\",\"url\":\"www.amazon.com\" }}" 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But problem was that Android and iOS users were subscribed to the same topic so I had to create double topic for iOS and Android separated so I can send the right payload. Or does Amazon handle it all, for example: I create one topic,Android and iOS users subscribe to the same topic, so I only have to send this JSON you posted and Amazon knows who is iOS and who is Android?

Comment: I just tested it, When you send it all at once, amazon takes care of it automatically. Great :D